# Can we make an uneven terrain like mountain or a dome as is floor constraint is used on the complete surface?

Tags: modeling, rigging, objects, faces, edges

When floor constraint is used its mostly interaction with plains the origins of the objects. Is there a way to make an uneven terrain like mountain or a dome as if floor constraint is used on the complete surface? The target object should not pass through the full terrain not just a plain where the origin is present.